# Unable to boot ubuntu 12.04, system does not respond to F? keys to boot from CD

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, boot-failure

I'm trying to dual boot my new laptop, downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu 64 bit, burnt it to a DVD, it boots as it's supposed to on my brother's laptop, not on mine, I did everything I could, modified the boot configuration using easyBCD, still doesn't boot into Ubuntu, from the boot menu I only see windows 7, when I installed Linux mint 2 days ago it booted correctly, had to remove it because I faced installation errors and switched to Ubuntu to try it, it just doesn't boot no matter what. how can U fix this? U don't see no errors and I have pressed all the <kbd>f?</kbd> buttons, I just see windows.

Comment: Did you go into `Bios` and make the boot priority, your CD/DVD drive?

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 i'm unable to go to BIOS, i tried F1, F2, DEL, ESC, F10 and couldn't go to bios, none of these buttons worked

Comment: Could you tell me what laptop it is?

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 hp pavilion g6

Comment: Scratch that, the key is F2 or F6 on some models [source](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c00364979&lc=en&man_lang=fr&product=5068623&query=G6-1051ex&tool=#N82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked online, and found that key is either <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Here is the [source](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c00364979&lc=en&man_lang=fr&product=5068623&query=G6-1051ex&tool=#N82) of where I got that information, and also how to change the boot order.

Hope this solves it. Have fun with the install!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are stating the install dvd is not booting on your system. Im also assuming that you have done a hcl compatibility verification and your pc should normally boot that distro. also when booting hit the key for the boot menu esc f11 and f12 are common ones. Then select boot from cd/dvd

Did you verify the write of the disk when you made it.  Did you make the disk on your pc or another pc.  It is not unusual to see a disk burned on a desktop not read properly on a laptop drive. Different drives don't always read home made disks properly especially laptop drives. You may want to burn another copy on the pc your trying to install to and possibly tell it not to use the fastes write speed, also make sure you have good media and do a verify of the media after burning.

Comment: i'm unable to go to BIOS, i tried F1, F2, DEL, ESC, F10 and couldn't go to bios, none of these buttons worked, I'll try again, i burnt it using nero 11 on my brother's toshiba, i have an hp so that might be the issue as u said

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem.
first download the ISO. image from the awesome Ubuntu site or any other Linux version.
then download a software called magiciso. which works on windows, then it'll hep you open the ISO. file then in the file contents you'll find a installation folder.install it then it'll ask for reboot. after reboot you'll find some more installation process which is a little lengthy. your Linux version is installed.